# Python Print Error because of Indents

Tags: python, indentation

I am running an insertion sort algorithm, and it seems to have a fault in it.  So I tried adding print statements to follow along, however when I include the print statements I get indent errors.  Can someone explain why the first code does not cause a problem but the second code does?

Runs Fine:

```
def isort(self):
    for i in range(1, len(self.array)):
        temp = self.array[i]
        k = i
        while k > 0 and temp < self.array[k-1]:
            # print self.array[k-1]
            self.array[k] = self.array[k-1]
            # print "k > 0 and temp < self.array[k-1]"
            # print "k: " + k
            # print "temp: " +temp
            # print "self.array[k-1]: " + self.array[k-1]
            k = k-1
        self.array[k] = temp
    return self.array
```

Errors located on lines with "#*"

```
    def isort(self):
    for i in range(1, len(self.array)):
        temp = self.array[i]
        k = i
        while k > 0 and temp < self.array[k-1]: #* indent expected
            print self.array[k-1] #* unexpected indent
            self.array[k] = self.array[k-1]
            # print "k > 0 and temp < self.array[k-1]" #* unindent does not match any outer indention level
            print "k: " + k
            # print "temp: " +temp
            # print "self.array[k-1]: " + self.array[k-1]
            k = k-1 #* unexpected indent
        self.array[k] = temp
    return self.array #* return outside of function
```

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing space and tab for indentation. Judging from the source of the question, lines up to and including `while` use tabs, those after use spaces.

Comment: BTW, as far as I can tell, your insertion sort seems to sort just fine.

Comment: @tobias_k for some reason it does not sort one of my arrays correctly.  It works for my random sorted array and 20% sorted array, but for my 40% sorted array the algorithm gets stuck in the while loop like its a forever loop.  Maybe my 40% array is screwed up.  Thanks for letting me know tho.

Comment: Made a loop to create random unsorted arrays of length 100 to test your sort and compare it to the result of builtin sort, let it run for a couple thousand iterations. All were sorted correctly and none went into infinite loop... The way your algo works, it can not get stuck. Both loops can only run at max `len(array)` iterations. If the problem persists after fixing the indentation, you might want to post this as a new question, including the array it fails on.

Comment: So, were you able to fix your indentation? And how did the sorting problem turn out?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing tabs and spaces for indentation.

In fact, even your first example (the one that works) has mixed tabs and spaces, but in this case they are somewhat consistent: The `while` is indented with two tabs, and all the non-comment lines after that with two tabs plus some spaces.

In the second example, the `while` is indented with two tabs, but the `print` line after that is indented with all spaces. Thus python can not work out what block this line should belong to.

In Python 2 you can use the `-t` option to check this; Python3 seems to check automatically.

```
>>> python2.6 -t test.py 
test.py: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

To fix it, you can do a *search-and-replace* to replace all tabs with groups 4 spaces or the other way around. The official way is four spaces, but [there is some debate on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming). Whatever, never mix!